# Looped delay question in Swift, what's the difference?

Tags: swift

So basically I've been trying to mess around with loops and delays in Swift. I've found multiple answers about how to implement it properly and I've also found answers how to do so. But I have one unanswered question.

Why does this delayed loop work:

```
for a in 1..<61 { 
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(a)) {
    print(a)
  }
}
```

while this doesnt have any delay besides the very first one:

```
for a in 1..<61 { 
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print(a)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops do not wait for the `DispatchQueue`. Using a `DispatchQueue` is like saying:

> "I want this work to be moved over to another thread (in this case the main thread, so doesn't change) by some deadline (how long until the work will happen)".

Since the loop does not wait, in the second example, **everything** is executed after 1 second.

However, in the first case, the delay is offset by different amounts. First iteration is in 2 seconds, then 3, then 4, etc.

*Note: Delays inside loops are not recommended. There are usually other solutions, such as using timers.*

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, at the end of the delay it's being delayed by 60 seconds, but since 59 passed, it will in reality delay it by one second? because that's what happens now

Comment: @morwi The loop is from `1..<61`, so `1...60` inclusive. Also, you add 1 second every time. So your last iteration will take 61 seconds until it is executed.

Comment: @morwi I see the slight mistake, I corrected it. Forgot about the `+ 1`.

Comment: as of now, the loop works like I wanted for it to work, so prints (a) every second. that's why it's confusing for me, when you mentioned "First iteration is in 2 seconds, then 3, then 4, etc." EDIT: nevermind, I saw the edit and now your answer is clearer. now I totally get it, thanks and cheers!

Comment: @morwi Exactly right. The loop basically triggers all of the `DispatchQueue`s at once (since the loop does not wait). So the first print message is in 2 seconds, then 3, then 4. The difference between each one is 1 second.

Comment: thanks again, that's exactly what I understood from reading it at the beginning but may have worded it poorly with my first response.

Comment: @morwi I suggest using a [`Timer`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer) without the for loop, which may work better. `DispatchQueue` is not 100% reliable, it is mostly an approximate time to run some code.